# how to add a variable to an SQL query?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to add argv[0] as variable to the SQL query below and running into compilation error below,what is the syntax to fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
from sys import argv
component_id=argv[0]
server_name='odsdb.company.com'
database_name='ODS'

    cnx = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+server_name+";DATABASE="+database_name)
    db_cursor=cnx.cursor()
    SQL = 'SELECT Top 1 cr.ReleaseLabel ' + \
    'FROM [ODS].[v000001].[ComponentRevisions] cr ' + \
    'WHERE cr.ComponentId=' + component_id + \
    'ORDER BY cr.CreatedOn DESC' 
    resp_rows_obj=db_cursor.execute(SQL)
    print '('+', '.join([column_heading_tuple[0] for column_heading_tuple in resp_rows_obj.description])+')'
    for row in resp_rows_obj:
        print row
```

Error:-

```
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: (u'42000', u"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'.")
```

Comment: Have you actually tried `print`ing `SQL` to see what it looks like?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: common enough mistake, thinking you can just put values into the string. Solution: teach about SQL parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use string interpolation. Use SQL parameters; these are placeholders in the query where your database will insert values:

```
SQL = '''\
    SELECT Top 1 cr.ReleaseLabel
    FROM [ODS].[v000001].[ComponentRevisions] cr
    WHERE cr.ComponentId = ?
    ORDER BY cr.CreatedOn DESC
'''
resp_rows_obj = db_cursor.execute(SQL, (component_id,))
```

Values for the `?` placeholders are sourced from the second argument to the `cursor.execute()` function, a sequence of values. Here you only have one value, so I used a one-element tuple.

Note that you probably want `argv[1]`, **not** `argv[0]`; the latter is the script name, not the first argument.

Comment: @i get an error pypyodbc.DataError: (u'22018', u"[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'odsdb.py' to data type int.")

Comment: @user3654069: Ah, yes, you are trying to pass in the script name.

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve 1st command line argument do `component_id=argv[1]` instead of 0 which is the script name...

better yet, look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

Answer (score 0):

We had a hyphen in the database name that was being used in a T-SQL query being called from Python code.  So we just added square brackets because SQL Server cannot interpolate the hyphen without them.

Before:

```
SELECT * FROM DBMS-NAME.dbo.TABLE_NAME
```

After:

```
SELECT * FROM [DBMS-NAME].dbo.TABLE_NAME
```